# React Native (Android) :app:bundleReleaseResources Error

Tags: android, react-native, production

When I am trying to build my React Native Android app to production I am getting this error saying :app:bundleReleaseResources.

Here is the full terminal log.

```
Configure project :react-native-google-mobile-ads
:react-native-google-mobile-ads package.json found at /Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/node_modules/react-native-google-mobile-ads/package.json
:react-native-google-mobile-ads package.json found at /Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/node_modules/react-native-google-mobile-ads/package.json
:react-native-google-mobile-ads:version set from package.json: 8.1.0 (8,1,0 - 8001000)
:react-native-google-mobile-ads:android.compileSdk using custom value: 31
:react-native-google-mobile-ads:android.targetSdk using custom value: 31
:react-native-google-mobile-ads:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-google-mobile-ads:reactNativeAndroidDir /Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/node_modules/react-native/android

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:packageReleaseRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-google-mobile-ads:packageReleaseRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-restart:packageReleaseRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-safe-area-context:packageReleaseRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-screens:packageReleaseRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
warning: the transform cache was reset.
                Welcome to Metro v0.72.3
              Fast - Scalable - Integrated


info Writing bundle output to:, /Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle
info Writing sourcemap output to:, /Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/intermediates/sourcemaps/react/release/index.android.bundle.packager.map
info Done writing bundle output
info Done writing sourcemap output
info Copying 7 asset files
info Done copying assets
/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:2030:23: warning: the variable "DebuggerInternal" was not declared in function "__shouldPauseOnThrow"
        return typeof DebuggerInternal !== 'undefined' && DebuggerInternal.shouldPauseOnThrow === true;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:5831:7: warning: the variable "setTimeout" was not declared in function "logCapturedError"
      setTimeout(function () {
      ^~~~~~~~~~
/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:4179:23: warning: the variable "clearTimeout" was not declared in anonymous function " 89#"
      cancelTimeout = clearTimeout;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:8826:30: warning: the variable "__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__" was not declared in anonymous function " 89#"
  if ("undefined" !== typeof __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__) {
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:8844:146: warning: the variable "nativeFabricUIManager" was not declared in anonymous function " 118#"
    null != handle._nativeTag && (null != handle._internalInstanceHandle ? (handle = handle._internalInstanceHandle.stateNode, null != handle && nativeFabricUIManager.dispatchCommand(handle.node, command, args)) : _$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[2]).UIManager.dispatchViewManagerCommand(handle._nativeTag, command, args));
                                                                                                                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:9807:5: warning: the variable "setImmediate" was not declared in function "handleResolved"
    setImmediate(function () {
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:13343:12: warning: the variable "fetch" was not declared in anonymous function " 290#"
    fetch: fetch,
           ^~~~~
/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:13344:14: warning: the variable "Headers" was not declared in anonymous function " 290#"
    Headers: Headers,
             ^~~~~~~
/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:13345:14: warning: the variable "Request" was not declared in anonymous function " 290#"
    Request: Request,
             ^~~~~~~
/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:13346:15: warning: the variable "Response" was not declared in anonymous function " 290#"
    Response: Response
              ^~~~~~~~
/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:13522:24: warning: the variable "FileReader" was not declared in function "readBlobAsArrayBuffer"
      var reader = new FileReader();
                       ^~~~~~~~~~
/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:13567:36: warning: the variable "Blob" was not declared in anonymous function " 301#"
        } else if (support.blob && Blob.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body)) {
                                   ^~~~
/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:13569:40: warning: the variable "FormData" was not declared in anonymous function " 301#"
        } else if (support.formData && FormData.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body)) {
                                       ^~~~~~~~
/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:13571:44: warning: the variable "URLSearchParams" was not declared in anonymous function " 301#"
        } else if (support.searchParams && URLSearchParams.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body)) {
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:13848:23: warning: the variable "XMLHttpRequest" was not declared in anonymous function " 310#"
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:13355:76: warning: the variable "self" was not declared in anonymous function " 293#"
    var global = typeof globalThis !== 'undefined' && globalThis || typeof self !== 'undefined' && self || typeof global !== 'undefined' && global;
                                                                           ^~~~
/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:22407:27: warning: the variable "performance" was not declared in anonymous function " 494#"
  if ("object" === typeof performance && "function" === typeof performance.now) {
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:22433:26: warning: the variable "navigator" was not declared in anonymous function " 494#"
  "undefined" !== typeof navigator && undefined !== navigator.scheduling && undefined !== navigator.scheduling.isInputPending && navigator.scheduling.isInputPending.bind(navigator.scheduling);
                         ^~~~~~~~~
/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:22513:37: warning: the variable "MessageChannel" was not declared in anonymous function " 494#"
  };else if ("undefined" !== typeof MessageChannel) {
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:31210:32: warning: the variable "requestAnimationFrame" was not declared in function "onUpdate"
        this._animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(this.onUpdate.bind(this));
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> Task :app:bundleReleaseResources FAILED
> Task :app:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 3 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ProcessResourcesRunnable
   > Android resource linking failed
     /Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/intermediates/bundle_manifest/release/AndroidManifest.xml:36: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.indigosolutions.zikirmatik:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.
     error: failed processing manifest.


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     /Users/furkanayilmaz/Desktop/Code/zikirmatik/android/app/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml:36: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.indigosolutions.zikirmatik:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.
     error: failed processing manifest.


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Execution optimizations have been disabled for 1 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.

BUILD FAILED in 20s
129 actionable tasks: 29 executed, 100 up-to-date
```

I have been trying to figure out this issue for a long time. All my images are in the proper section res folder. I could not find a proper information on Google on regards to how to solve this